# How does returning Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> work?

Tags: rust, error-handling

I've seen code like this:

```
use std::error::Error;
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
   Err("March")?
}
```

And:

```
use std::error::Error;
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
   Err("March".into())
}
```

But I really don't understand how they work. As far as I know, `?` acts like an early return that returns immediately when we run into an error. Then why do we need `Err("March")?`? Why not just `Err("March")` as it's already the last expression of the function?

`Err("March".into())` is even more puzzling for me. What does `"March".into()` return and if it's already returning an error, why do we need to wrap it in `Err()` again? Why this doesn't cause weird type like `Err(Err())`?

Comment: `"March"`, a `&'static str`, is not a `Box<dyn Error>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"March".into()` has a generic type which gets resolved by inference. That generic type is inferred to be `Box<dyn Error>` based on the return type.

The question mark operator works because it desugars to something which eventually calls `into()` on the error value. `Err("March")?` becomes roughly something like

```
match Err("March") { Ok(val) => val, Err(e) => return Err(e.into()) }
```

The actual desugaring is more complicated (mainly because it will also handle conversions between e.g. Option and Result) but roughly looks like the above.

Comment: I'm trying to understand in this case, which struct is implementing the `From` trait invoked by `e.into()`? Would this implementation be found on Box, `impl<T> From<T> for Box<T> `?

Comment: @flakes are you looking for [`impl From<&str> for Box<dyn Error>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3C%26str%3E-for-Box%3Cdyn+Error,+Global%3E)?

Comment: @cafce25 Ah thank you! Looks like I was looking at the wrong implementation. That impl makes much more sense now that I think about it some more.

Comment: Now I see that I can replace `Box::new(err)` with just `err.into()` for a lot of my code :)

Comment: Fun fact: [`?` exclusively uses `From`; it does not use `Into`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a75d7a342a328f2a0d255f95704872d9). I learned this a few days ago and was honestly rather surprised. So the `Err` arm should be `return Err(From::from(e));`.